# How to motion blur with ImageMagick using wand?

Tags: python, imagemagick, blur, motion, wand

I want to use motion blur with ImageMagick. 
[Motion blur in ImageMagick documentation.](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#motion-blur)

But in Wand there is only gaussian_blur.
[Gaussian blur in Wand documentation.](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.3/wand/image.html)

Is motion blur missing in wand?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Looks like an app tech support question.

Comment: You can ask for support here: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=6

Answer (score 1):

> Is motion blur missing in wand?

Yes, as of *0.4.3* there is no `wand.image.Image.motion_blur` method implemented on [wand](/questions/tagged/wand) library.

You'll need to extend wand's API to include [`MagickMotionBlurImage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickMotionBlurImage).

```py
import ctypes
from wand.image import Image
from wand.api import library

# Tell Python about the C method
library.MagickMotionBlurImage.argtypes = (ctypes.c_void_p,  # wand
                                          ctypes.c_double,  # radius
                                          ctypes.c_double,  # sigma
                                          ctypes.c_double)  # angle

# Extend wand.image.Image class to include method signature (remember error handling)
class MyImage(Image):
    def motion_blur(self, radius=0.0, sigma=0.0, angle=0.0):
        library.MagickMotionBlurImage(self.wand,
                                      radius,
                                      sigma,
                                      angle)


# Example usage
with MyImage(filename='rose:') as img:
    img.motion_blur(radius=8.0, sigma=4.0, angle=-57.0)
    img.save(filename='rose_motion.png')
```

[image]